# Python: display IFrame

Tags: iframe, ipython, python-3.3

I am trying a sample code that is supposed to use IPython and display a html file.
Here is part of the code that is relevant to my question:

```
from IPython.display import IFrame
from IPython.core.display import display

display(IFrame('myfile.html', '100%', '600px'))
```

But when I run it, nothing shows up. What could be the reason?

Do I need to install something related to `d3` or `d3js`?

Comment: If you start an Ipython notebook and enter any input do you get output? If not, then you have a firewall problem, that is unrelated to your code. This is typical when using it for the first time...

Comment: Woody: I do not use Ipython notebook, I just use IDLE (Python GUI).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in a Jupyter notebook (it doesn't display anything when tested in a terminal running IPython) - It will not display anything if the file is empty or contains malformed HTML. If the file doesn't exist you'll see a 404 displayed in the IFrame.